# OK Button crashes in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, windows-xp

I'm working on XP and using WX python As GUI library. Recently I look a lot of problems, for example If I Use a  [@MikeDriscoll 's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693660/ok-cancel-order-in-custom-dialogs-created-with-wxglade) the code at the second print the python interpreter crashes, and I don't know why and how track this error (more important)...

```
import wx

########################################################################
class SampleDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title="Tutorial")
        print "Hello Here"
        btnOk = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK)
        print "Hello Here"
        btnCancel = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        btnSizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
        btnSizer.AddButton(btnOk)
        btnSizer.AddButton(btnCancel)
        btnSizer.Realize()
        self.SetSizer(btnSizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    dlg = SampleDialog(None)
    dlg.ShowModal()
```

Comment: I'm not receiving a crash. You do seem to be missing a dlg.Destroy() and an app.MainLoop() at the end of your example though. Are you trying to run this from within IDLE? What OS, wxPython and Python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Window XP as OS, wx python 3.0.0.0, Python 2.7, I added also dlg.Destroy() and app.MainLoop() and neither, it doesn't work. I'm not using IDLE, but command prompt from DOS. The weird thing is that about one month ago all stuffs worked fine.

Comment: I don't know why.... but with wx 2.8.12.1 it works!

Comment: Sounds like a bug then. I would submit a bug report and / or ask on the wxPython Google group

Comment: I'll try to submit the bug. Thanks Mike - P.S.: I read your blog ;)

Comment: This code snippet works fine on Windows 8, wxPython v3.0 and python v2.7